# Wireguard not reconnect after network cable reconnected

Tags: wireguard

I am currently testing with my wireguard ubuntu setup. But I have a problem with the vpn connection it is not reestablished after unplugging and plugging the network cable. If i unplug the switch from the uplink it works without problem.

Is there a solution for this?

My client config

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.100.0.2/32
PrivateKey = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
DNS = 10.100.0.1

[Peer]
PublicKey = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
Endpoint = 123.123.123.123:51820
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

Comment: What is the platform for the client ? Linux, BSD, Windows  ?

Comment: @Dom It is in my question `ubuntu`